# On focus event (jQuery) trigger a mouse click goTo href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the site to navigate another page within the same site when the button is in focus. So just as when you click on the button it takes the user to a page in the site, I would like that when a user 'focuses' on a button using tab, the browser navigates to the page as if the button was selected.

I have tried several methods but none seem to work, here is what I am currently working with,

```
<script>  
 $('a.link, .nav-item').focus (function(){

    if (.focus === true) {
     .trigger('click');
   }
 });
</script>
```

[current project link](https://dashboard-v26.webflow.io/)

Comment: The whole point of being able to navigate using the tab is for accessibility - It seems like there's no point in doing what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the location with window.location. No need to simulate the click.

I will say however that this isn't gonna be best practice, what if the user inadvertently clicks tab or something? This is much harder to control than just leaving it as a button click. But I digress, the choice is yours and here is how you can do it :)

```js
$('#tabbyRef').focus(function(){
  window.location = $('#tabbyRef').attr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">First one</a>
<br>
<a href="#">Second one</a>
<br>
<a id="tabbyRef" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Tab to me</a>
```

**EDIT:**

You can start with a specific element set by a few different ways.

First way: Get all  elements and just focus on any random one. I selected the 2nd one here.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    x = $(document).find('a');
    $(x[1]).focus();
})

$('#tabbyRef').focus(function(){
  window.location = $('#tabbyRef').attr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">First one</a>
<br>
<a href="#">Second one</a>
<br>
<a id="tabbyRef" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Tab to me</a>
```

Second Way: Use Id's or check the value of the hrefs to start here.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="waffle"]').focus();
})

$('#tabbyRef').focus(function(){
  window.location = $('#tabbyRef').attr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">First one</a>
<br>
<a href="waffle">Second one</a>
<br>
<a id="tabbyRef" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Tab to me</a>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked very well. For context we are prototyping for TV ui and trying to re-create some of the interaction commonly found on internet TV sites. This is why we are breaking traditional web based best practices. Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: Do you know how I might set the focus on a specific <a href="#"></a>? For example, if on page I want the focus to start on 'Second once' like in the above example, is it possible?

Comment: @ChrisPennell See my edit. I can think of literally 20 ways to do this off of the top of my head. Here are 2 ways. If this helps feel free to upvote and select as answer :)

Answer (score -1):

try...

```
$('a.link, .nav-item').focus(onFocus);


function onFocus() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.focus === true) {
        $this.click();
    }
}
```